# Connecting to VPN in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have used a VPN service and used java code for connecting to it and running it on Ubuntu.Whenever the sudo openvpn command runs completely the console gets stuck and doesn't go to the code after the while loop.But if I include the code after the sudo command inside the while loop it runs the code after that but not the sudo command then. I tries adding "&" so that the command runs in the background but no use.Please suggest a method to do this as i have tried various solutions but all in vain.Below is my code that i have written.

```
public class curl {


void sudo() throws IOException {

    String command1 = "sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/configFile ";

     System.out.println(command1);



     Process curlProc1;

    curlProc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);



    DataInputStream curlIn1 = new DataInputStream(

            curlProc1.getInputStream());

      String outputString1;

     while ((outputString1 = curlIn1.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(outputString1);

}


     String urly = "MyURL";
             URL obj = new URL(urly);
             HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

             con1.setRequestMethod("GET");

           con1.setDoOutput(true);

             int responseCode = con1.getResponseCode();
             System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

             BufferedReader iny = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(con1.getInputStream()));
               String output;
               StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

               while ((output = iny.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(output);

               }

               iny.close();
               System.out.println(response.toString());
               }

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, JSONException{

     curl brc= new curl();
     brc.sudo();

}



}
```

Comment: inheritIO might be a better solution here: http://www.owsiak.org/java-python-and-io-inheritance/

Comment: can you please provide an example related to my code ? :(

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by the fact that sudo outputs to the error stream. This is happening:

> ```
> curlProc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
> ```

1. Your program starts sudo
2. Since sudo by defaults works on a terminal bases, it outputs either "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" or "Password: " to `stderr`

> ```
> while ((outputString1 = curlIn1.readLine()) != null) {
> ```

3. Your program waits for input on the `stdout`
4. Since you never read the stderr, sudo will never terminate, and hence, sudo will never close the stdout, so your program stays stuck

One quick way to fix this is by using a [process builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), this has the usefull option to combine both the `stderr` and the `stdout` in a single stream, meaning you only need 1 thread to read the stream, and keeping your code simple.

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
    new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "openvpn", "--config", "/etc/openvpn/configFile");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process curlProc1 = pb.start();
....
```

Since there is a chance that sudo will ask for a password ([you can configure it to ask for one instead of giving an error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers)), you can supply a password by writing to the input stream of the process *after*  getting the password prompt:

```
p.getOutputStream().write("correct battery horse staple\n".getBytes(STandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: I tried for this solution too but the problem still persists and it is around the while loop.If i close the loop  the code after that doesn't executes at all but the sudo command works perfectly.The code after the while loop executes only if i add it into the while loop but then the sudo command doesn't run. Can we use something else instead of readLine()?Maybe when i add the code inside the loop it can't execute the whole sudo command and the code after that runs immediately.